# How do you show a DialogPreference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

- Here is a random layout called **some_layout**.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"">

      <!-- Some views in here -->

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```
- Here is a class **SomeDialog**.java that extends DialogPreference:

  ```
  import android.content.Context;

  import androidx.preference.DialogPreference;

  public class SomeDialog extends DialogPreference {


      public SomeDialog(Context context) {
          super(context);
      }

      @Override
      public int getDialogLayoutResource() {
          return R.layout.some_layout;
      }
  }
  ```
- And here's the preference screen:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <android.example.perappbrightness.SomeDialog
              android:title="@string/rate_app"
              android:summary="@string/rate_summary"
              android:key="rate_app"/>

  </PreferenceScreen>
  ```

Relevant part of crash error. The line at which `MainActivty` crashes is `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.example.perappbrightness/android.example.perappbrightness.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.example.perappbrightness.SomeDialog
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.example.perappbrightness.SomeDialog
android.example.perappbrightness.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
```

**SettingsActivity**.java is an untouched. It's from the template of Android Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the rest of the error message as well as the code where you actually use the PreferenceScreen resource. Ideally as much code as I need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BömachtBlau Hi. My SettingsActivity is untouched, like Android Studio generates it by default. But I will post it anyway.

Comment: If you just let Android Studio set up some template classes, no need to post anything. Just tell us what you did so far. Plus the error message :)

Comment: @BömachtBlau Is it good now?

Comment: Yes, thanks. My Android Studio complains that the ...SomeDialog element is not allowed in the PreferenceScreen. When I start the app anyway, it crashes with the same message

Comment: So how does one open a Dialog by clicking on a Preference?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out - or rather I'm trying to find out what's missing in your setup (and I' not doing preference screens every week ;-) ).... The problem seems to be that you only have the constructor with parameter Context for SomeDialog. If I add all the constructors except for  SomeDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes), the app does not crash anymore

Comment: This seems to be the case for anything (Views) which may be inflated from xml. If you write a custom View class and you're sure that you only will create it programmatically then the Context constructor will do.

Comment: @BömachtBlau did you successfully open a Dialog by clicking on the preference?

Comment: @BömachtBlau I don't understand. Why isn't there an online tutorial or example for how to do this very basic thing? Why do we have t discover it on our own? The preference screen has been around for how many years? > 10? The very vague related answers on SO say that both a `PreferenceDialog` and a `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` need to be created but not much details beyond that. Anyway, did you get it working?

Comment: I absolutely agree, the absence of guides/ codelabs is really frustrating...  it seems you have to override a method  onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference) in the (template) SettingsFragment. And I'm still trying to make it work, I'll get back to you as soon as I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add more constructors to `SomeDialog`. The `Context` constructor is not enough since the `Preference` will be inflated from `xml`. Having the following three constructors is usually sufficient:

```
public SomeDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SomeDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SomeDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

In addition to that, the `SettingsFragment` in your `SettingsActivity` needs to implement `onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference)` to show a custom dialog for the custom `Preference`.

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
        if (preference instanceof SomeDialog) {
            MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(MyDialogFragment.KEY, preference.getKey());
            b.putInt(MyDialogFragment.KEY_LAYOUT_RES_ID,  ((SomeDialog) preference).getDialogLayoutResource());

            dialogFragment.setArguments(b);
            dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        } else super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
    }
}
```

And, last not least, you also have to provide the custom dialog itself. This is done via a class extending `DialogFragment`.

My very simple `DialogFragment` has a `TextView` inside a `FrameLayout`, just to show it works

[image: very ugly dialog showing preference key]

MyDialogFragment code:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String KEY = "key";
    public static final String KEY_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "resid";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(requireArguments().getInt(KEY_LAYOUT_RES_ID), container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(requireArguments().getString(KEY));
    }
}
```

Comment: since setTargetFragment is now deprecated, is there an alternative to this method?

Comment: @brassmookie - there are various alternatives. One option is to have a shared ViewModel for Fragment and DialogFragment, see for example ["Share data between fragments"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)